# How to render a region in custom module twig template

Tags: 8, theming

I have rendered regions in page.html.twig using `{{ page.region_name }}`. But it doesn't work for the custom modules template. How can I render a region in custom template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend to install the [Twig Tweak module](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak): It provides ([amongst others](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet-8x-2x)) an operator for that:
`{{ drupal_region('my_region_name') }}`